# .NET regular expression for a relatively simple string format

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to construct a regular expression for the following:

- 6 characters exactly
- Alphanumerical characters only
- Letters are all uppercase
- There are exactly 1, 3, 4 or 5 letters at the beginning, the rest must be numbers

How do I go about that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I'd write it (using C# in free-spacing mode):

```php
if (Regex.IsMatch(text, @"
    # Match specific string with multiple requirements.
    ^                      # Anchor to start of string.
    (?=.{6}$)              # 6 characters exactly.
    (?:                    # There are exactly
      [A-Z]{3,5}           # 3, 4, 5 or
    | [A-Z]                # 1, uppercase letters
    )                      # at the beginning,
    [0-9]+                 # the rest must be numbers.
    $                      # Anchor to end of string.", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

**Edit:** Changed from PHP to C#/.NET syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer to use more than just regex to get more humaa readability

```
var input = "ABC456";
return input.Length==6 && Regex.IsMatch(input,@"^([A-Z]|[A-Z]{3,5})\d+$");
```

Answer (score 2):

**Abdicate**

*Definition refactor*:
- 6 total characters, capital letter and number chars only
- first must be a letter, last a number
- first letter is optionally followed by 2 to 4 letters

*Method 1*:

`^(?=.{6}$)[A-Z](?:[A-Z]{2,4})?\d+$`

(expanded)

```
^
(?= .{6} $ )
[A-Z] (?:[A-Z]{2,4})? \d+ $
```

*Method 2*:

`^(?=[A-Z](?:(?<!\d)[A-Z]|\d){4}\d$)[A-Z](?:[A-Z]{2,4})?\d`

(expanded)

```
^
(?= [A-Z] (?: (?<!\d)[A-Z] | \d ){4} \d $ )
[A-Z] (?:[A-Z]{2,4})? \d
```

Method 2 doesn't require an end anchor because the assertion is length and end specific, but is made to appear slow/cumbersome by the lookbehind (due to OP's conditions).

For this reason I would go with a Method 1 regex, although I believe the other would obtain better speed bench's, which is probably irrelavent over code clarity in this case.

Comment: The assertion: `(?=[A-Z]|[A-Z]{3,5}\d+)` needs one more set of parens and an end anchor: `(?=([A-Z]|[A-Z]{3,5})\d+$)`. As-is, it erroneously matches: `ABCDEF`, `A123EF`, etc.

Comment: +1 for using ?=  (new thing to me)

Comment: @ridgerunner - Cut'nPaste error, it does need the parenthesis but doesen't need the end anchor as you say, the []{6} expression qualifies the length.

Comment: @sin - the anchor _is_ required. Otherwise strings like `A2CDEF` and `ABC4EF` will match.

Comment: @rigrunnr - thanks, fixed I hope. The anchor isin't required there now.

Comment: Not fixed yet. Still erroneously matches `A2CDE6` and `ABC4E6`.

Comment: @ridgerunner - Wow, your right! Fixed version is there now, hows that one? I've seen the light, the end anchor is the simpler solution. Thanks!

Comment: Your new method 1 is accurate and is the most efficient solution presented thus far (its better than mine which uses slower alternation - nice job!) However, that method 2 of yours has evolved into quite the rube-goldberg affair! (Although it does now appear to work).

Answer (score 1):

`^[A-Z](([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3})|([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2})|([A-Z]{4}[0-9]{1})|([0-9]{5}))$`

UPDATED: Now matches all requirements

Answer (score 1):

```
^([A-Z]\d{5})|([A-Z]{3}\d{3})|([A-Z]{4}\d{2})|([A-Z]{5}\d)$
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick on the top of my head. There may be shorter more elegant versions..

```
bool foundMatch = false;
try {
    foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, @"\A(?:(?:[A-Z]\d{5})|(?:[A-Z]{3}\d{3})|(?:[A-Z]{4}\d{2})|(?:[A-Z]{5}\d))\Z");
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```